# Why must isometry of regular polygon fix origin?

Tags: symmetry, polygons

Here is the question:

> Suppose $\varphi\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is an isometry and $\varphi(\pi_n)=\pi_n$, where $\pi_n$ is the regular $n$-gon with center at origin. Why must $\varphi$ fix the origin or the center?

Here, I don't want to use the fact that $\varphi$ is a permutation of vertices of $\pi_n$, because it is actually equivalent to the question I asked, and I don't know its proof either.

I think this question is really easy, because intuitively it is correct. However, I want to prove it rigorously and don't know how to proceed.

---

**Partial Answer:**

I came up with a proof for $n=2q$ and am not sure if it is correct.

If $\varphi$ is an isometry and $S[A,B]$ is a line segment between $A\in\Bbb R^2$ and $B\in\Bbb R^2$, then $\varphi(S[A,B])=S[\varphi(A),\varphi(B)]$ and the length is also preserved. In particular, the midpoint of $S[A,B]$ is mapped to the midpoint of $S[\varphi(A),\varphi(B)]$. Take two vertices $v_i,v_j$ such that $O\in S[v_i,v_j]$ and consider four facts:
(1) Every regular polygon has a circumscribed circle.
(2) $S[v_i,v_j]$ is the diameter of the circumscribe circle.
(3) Vertices of $\pi_n$ are on the circle.
(4) $\varphi(\pi_n)=\pi_n$

Combining the four facts above, $\varphi(v_i)$ and $\varphi(v_j)$ must also be vertices of $\pi_n$, so that the midpoint of $S[\varphi(v_i),\varphi(v_j]$ is the center $O$. Therefore, the origin $O$ is preserved.

Comment: Why can't you use the fact that $\phi$ is a permutation? Or are you saying that you don't know how to use that fact?

Comment: @Calvin Lin Actually, I was originally asked to prove that $\varphi$ is a permutation of vertices. However, I found that this is true if and only if $\varphi$ fixes the origin or the center. Besides, I don't want to just use this fact without any proof. Therefore, I turn myself to the proof that every isometry of regular polygon fixes the origin or the center.

Comment: [Euclid III:9](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII9.html) can be adapted to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:** Circumcenter.

> There is a unique point that is equidistant from all the vertices.

**Approach 2:** Incenter.

> There is a unique point that is equidistant from all the sides.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the approach 1? Actually, I tried it but still can't prove it.

Comment: @Y.Fan What do you need an elaboration on? Do you agree that such a point is uniquely determined by the distances? If so, then the isometry must map that point to itself.

Comment: I think that you are implicitly using the fact that isometries are permutations of vertices. Am I right?

Comment: @Y.Fan Yes I am. All that I need is that it's a permutation of the vertices (which is obvious). In fact, it's a rotation possibly combined with a reflection (which is also obvious, perhaps less so).

Comment: Yes, I know it Is obvious, but I still want a rigorous proof. I have already given one for even number of vertices.

Comment: @Y.Fan Is it obvious that the perimeter must map to the perimeter? If so, the intersection of 2 lines of the perimeter must map to the intersection of 2 lines of the perimeter. Hence, the vertices must map to the vertices. How prove that the vertices must map in order.

Comment: How do you define a regular polygon? just the boundary or the whole shape? if it Is the latter, why lines on perimeter goes to perimeter?

Comment: @Y.Fan If it's the latter then "kinks" must map to "kinks".

Comment: I am sorry, but what exactly is a kink?

Comment: A bend, a joint, a break, an endpoint. Take whatever term you will use to define a vertex, given the perimeter.

Comment: what i am worried about is that vertices just go inside and some other inside kinks go to the vertices. if so, vertices wont go to vertices. why is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

A couple more approaches based on symmetry:

> An isometry must take every axis of mirror symmetry to a similar axis, so must fix the unique point where the axes of symmetry intersect

And also

> An isometry must take a centre of rotational symmetry to a similar centre. If there is only one such centre, it must be fixed.

These are not true for infinite configurations (wallpaper patterns, for example) where there can be an infinite number of axes/centres of symmetry which can be transformed into each other. It is the finiteness of the configuration which means that there is a single centre. If there is more than one, there must be an infinite number.